# imshow command for Gaussian function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I'm trying to plot 2D gaussian function using "imshow" in MATLAB. However I could not see any white points in image. I tried to change sampling values and limits of x and y values. In addition to this, I tried z.^2 and higher orders but nothing changed.Thank you for any help.What can be the problem? My code is below:

```
sigma = 10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-40:0.5:40,-40:0.5:40);
z     = (1/(2*pi*(sigma^2)))*exp(-((X.^2)+(Y.^2))/(2*(sigma^2)));
figure
surf(X,Y,z);%shading interp
figure
imshow(z);
```

[image: Using "surf" command]

[image: using "imshow" command]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to simply use either:

```
imagesc(z);
```

Or:

```
h=pcolor(z)
set(h, 'LineStyle','None')
```

Although if you really want to use `imshow` then provide a set of extra parameters to scale the plotting range. It's more computational and memory efficient.

```
imshow(z, [min(min(z)) max(max(z))])
```

Comment: It is good to learn that method. However I need to plot my image in grayscale.

Comment: `colormap gray`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the scale on your 3d plot. The z axis (or intensity value when plotted as an image) has an order of magnitude 10^-3

Imshow on any double (decimal) number in matlab automatically scales the image as 0=black 1= white. With that in mind you plot is essentially a matrix of zeros, or blacks.

You can solve this in two ways

1.Using imagesc, scales an image to take up the full dynamic range

```
imshow(imagesc(z));
```

2.Emulate imagesc

```
Max_val= max(max(z));
Min_val=min(min(z));
scaledz = 1/(Max_val - Min_val) * (z - Min_val); %this gets our numbers between 0-1
Imshow(scaledz)
```

**code isn't tested** I just wrote it from memory on my cell phone. It may not work exactly but it should be pretty close